# App compiled from Unity with cardboard is not getting installed

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am quiet new to vr but is using Unity for quiet a long. What I did is just followed all of the normal steps. Compiled the apk it's working in emulators, works on Android devices but is not working in my android device. 
My device : mi3w with mesh mellow miui8
Vr used to work in it (i have same sample pakages of old version of cardboard sdk apk generated via it works) all vr app in playstore works but the app I generate it just dosent gets installed. Installation always fails!

So right now iam really going crazy I can make the vr game show to other but can't run them on my own device!

Vr app I tried to install was total blank the one provided with cardboard sdk as demo

Any help would be apretiated 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Well, surely there should be some errors. I have mi3w myself and all of the app complied via unity for VR works like a charm. What u can try to do is to uninstall any previous version of the app that u may have installed and try to make a new VR project with bare minimums, Just to test if the issue is with the project or Android. Sometimes having the old package installed causes issues.